# Error in loading youtube, stackoverflow or facebook main pages into iframe tag

Tags: javascript, html

When i try to use the following code to load facebook or you youtube into iframe tags nothing is happened. page isn't loaded into iframe tag
this problem occurs with multiple sites such as youtube, stackoverflow and facebook

code:

```
        <head>
        <title>HTML Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        </head>

        <body>

        <p>Below is an iframe.</p>
        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/" width="400" height="150">
         <p>iframes are not supported by your browser.</p>
        </iframe>

        </body>
        </html>
```

any help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it

http://jsfiddle.net/KPk6n/1

And looking at the console, I get

> Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options

So I think those sites disallow framing, there probably is a workaround to this, but I'd say you should respect them and not frame them

Answer (score 0):

The sites you speak of probably disable access from iFrames.

My site works just fine in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/3vxvm/

Comment: I know a lot of other sites work fine but my problem is with these 3 sites

Comment: @naruto You apparently did not read my answer fully. Those sites must have some sort of script or header enabled to block iFrames from accessing their site.

Comment: First i appreciate your help, but you mean there is no solution to this problem

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying: **there is no solution because each of the sites you speak of block this behavior.**